# how i create a final table from two tables in nodejs and mysql after creating a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have two tables which are

```
doctor_collections(
  id(pk) ,name, address, gender, contact_no, email ,specialist ,degree
)
```

and

```
doctor_schedule_collections(
  id(pk) ,doctor_id(fk) ,date, duration, starting_time, ending_time ,fees
)
```

I want to fetch some data from these two tables and show them as a table on my website. The attributes will be name, address, gender ,specialist, degree, date ,duration, starting_time ,ending_time, fees.
For that I need to create an object in my API and send that object. Like this:

```
{
 name
 address
 gender
 specialist
 degree
 date
 duration
 starting_time
 ending_time
 fees
}
```

```
app.get("/all_schedule",(req,res)=>{
  con.query("select * from doctor_schedule_collections",(err,resp)=>{
    if(resp.length==0){

    }else{
    con.query("select * from doctor_collections where id=?",resp.doctor_id,(err,data)=>{
      res.send(data);
    })
    }
  })
})
```

This is not right because I am getting data asana array of objects and I am not able to fetch doctor_id by using resp.doctor_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting data asana array of objects

Well sure, since SQL Select query has zero or more results you'll have to iterate over each row in the result set.

> `"select * from doctor_collections where id=?",resp.doctor_id`

Any time you're iterating over one query result and running another query for each of the results, an alarm should go off in your head.  This is the wrong way to use sql.

To include doctor data along with the schedule query, You're looking for a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT * FROM doctor_schedule_collections 
  JOIN doctor_collections 
    ON (doctor_collections.id = doctor_collection_schedules.doctor_id)
```

Comment: It is absolutely right. Thank you so much.